# How to access screen size within javascript file

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

Hello I am using javascript file to format my html string in swift. This is my.js file

`

```
 var title = document.body
 title.style.color = 'white'
 title.style.display = 'block'


var iframe = document.body.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
iframe.style.width = '320'
iframe.height = '200'
```

`

for this `iframe.style.width = '320'` I want to give the screen width. How can I access screen width in my `.js` file?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: yeas. iphone screen width

Comment: Well, what I have posted is a JavaScript code snippet. `screen.width` returns the screen width of the window.

Comment: haha thanks. It worked